# db_query() and db_select() don't return any value

Tags: database

I'm trying to run the following query.

```sql
SELECT floormap_counter_expected.counter_name, tls_connect_agent_counters.counter_stage,tls_connect_agent_counters.applicant_gwf, tls_connect_agent_counters.counter_ip, floormap_counter_expected.expected FROM tls_connect_agent_counters INNER JOIN floormap_counter_expected ON floormap_counter_expected.counter_name = tls_connect_agent_counters.counter_name;
```

When executed via the command line, MYSQL returns the information I need.

When I try the following code, I get an error saying that `$center_counters` is not set.

```php
$get_counter_info = db_select('tls_connect_agent_counters', 't');
$get_counter_info->fields('t', array('counter_stage', 'applicant_gwf', 'counter_ip'));
$get_counter_info->fields('n', array('expected'));
$get_counter_info->join('floormap_counter_expected', 'n', 't.counter_name = n.counter_name');
$get_counter_info->execute()->fetchAll();
if (isset($get_counter_info)) {
  foreach ($get_counter_info as $results) {
    echo "Rest";
    $center_counters[$results->counter_name]['stage'] = $results->counter_stage;
    $center_counters[$results->counter_name]['counter_ip'] = $results->counter_ip;
    $i++;
  }
}
return $center_counters;
```

The same happens with the following code.

```php
$counters_query = "SELECT floormap_counter_expected.counter_name, tls_connect_agent_counters.counter_stage,";
$counters_query .= "tls_connect_agent_counters.applicant_gwf, tls_connect_agent_counters.counter_ip, ";
$counters_query .= "floormap_counter_expected.expected FROM tls_connect_agent_counters INNER JOIN ";
$counters_query .= "floormap_counter_expected ON floormap_counter_expected.counter_name = tls_connect_agent_counters.counter_name";
$get_counter_info = db_query($counters_query);
$get_counter_info->fetchAll();
if (isset($get_counter_info)) {
  foreach ($get_counter_info as $results) {
    echo "Rest";
    $center_counters[$results->counter_name]['stage'] = $results->counter_stage;
    $center_counters[$results->counter_name]['counter_ip'] = $results->counter_ip;
    $i++;
  }
}
return $center_counters;
```

I tried wrapping the code with `try{} catch(Exception $e) {echo $e-getMessage()}`, but nothing is printed.

I assume the query is running without error because nothing is "caught".

I was thinking that maybe I'm just calling the information wrong in my foreach loop. Maybe I should identify the table name as well when I call the field name. I don't think that is the case as nothing is printed when I try to echo strings out of `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_counter_info->execute()->fetchAll();
```

will execute the query...but what are you doing with the results, exactly? At the moment you're discarding them, instead you need to assign them to a variable.

```
$results = $get_counter_info->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $result) {
  ...
}
```

Or at the very least actually *use* the return value from the execution:

```
foreach ($get_counter_info->execute()->fetchAll() as $result) {
  ...
}
```